# Clone console.log function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to clone `console.log` method into a function. Let's call it `log`.

I tried:

```
log = console.log;
log (1);
> TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

This is happening only on the client side. I works fine on NodeJS console:

```
$ node
> log = console.log
[Function]
> log ("Hello World!")
Hello World!
undefined
```

The first question would be why: on the does it work fine on the server side but not on the client?

I want to override the `console.log` method, but after I save it into another variable.

```
 oldLog = console.log;
 console.log = function () {
     /* do my stuff */
     oldLog.apply(this, arguments);
 }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: @cookiemonster Related. I am asking why on NodeJS it works fine.

Comment: You're asking two different questions in one. That's a duplicate of one of your questions. As to why it works in NodeJS, why wouldn't it? There's no `console` defined in ECMAScript, so its behavior (or existence) is entirely implementation dependent.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: Because it was bound there explicitly. Works in clientside Opera as well, btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`console.log` requires that `this` be the `console` object.

If you call it as a standalone function, `this` will be `window`, so it won't work.

Node.js sets `console.log` to `console.log.bind(console)`, so it always works.
(see [source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/22c68fdc1dae40f0ed9c71a02f66e5b2c6353691/lib/console.js#L47-L49))

If you call it with the correct `this` (using `bind()` or `call()` or `apply()`), it will work in the browser too.